# Dropdown Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: html, bootstrap, menu, dropdown

Tinha feito um menu usando Bootstrap e ele estava funcionando perfeitamente, mas precisei acrescentar um dropdown, e aparentemente ele não exibe nenhum erro... Mas nada acontece ao clicar no menu.

```
      [![<div class="ma][1]][1]sthead">
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
        <li><a href="buy.html">Where to Buy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Os arquivos .css e .js do bootstrap também estão corretamente apontados para a página.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não funciona porque você adicionou o menu dropdown fora do elemento `li`. Basta inserí-lo que funcionará perfeitamente.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ma][1]][1]sthead">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="buy.html">Where to Buy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```